# Importing and working with a ruby gem

Tags: ruby, rubygems, rvm

My title might not accurately reflect what I'm trying to ask, but it's the best that I could come up with really.

What I'm trying to do is make modifications to a library, and to test those modifications in a project. So I've got RVM running, a project folder called `project/`, a gemset with 2.3.1, and the library git cloned into the folder `project/metasm/`. I have a file `project/Gemfile` which has this line in it:

```
gem "metasm", :path => "metasm"
```

And when I run `bundle install` I get the following:

```
Using metasm 1.0.2 from source at `metasm`
Using bundler 1.13.6
Bundle complete! 1 Gemfile dependency, 2 gems now installed.
Use `bundle show [gemname]` to see where a bundled gem is installed.
```

Good, so everything seems to work as it should. Awesome. I drop down into `irb` and go to `require` the library/gem, but it doesn't seem to work too well for me.

```
2.3.1 :001 > require "metasm"
LoadError: cannot load such file -- metasm
    from /home/chiggins/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from /home/chiggins/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from (irb):1
    from /home/chiggins/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/bin/irb:11:in `<main>'
```

Now here's what I'm not really understanding. Why can I not use `metasm` from where it currently is at, even though `bundle install` worked as it should?

This was the best way I thought that this would work. What I ideally want to do is be able to make my changes to the `metasm` library as I see fit and either run `irb` or a Ruby script to test/validate my changes. Is this a good way to go about it or should I go about it another way?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Are you entering irb using `bundle exec irb`?

Comment: It sounds like you've a copy of metasm in your gem directory for your ruby installation AND a copy of the its source within your probject. If you've got the source of the gem in your project folder, you're not really using it as "a gem". Does removing the Gemfile declaration and calling `require 'metasm/metasm'` work?

Comment: @LucasCosta -- If I do that and run `require "metasm"` it returns `false`.

@Kache -- Removing the entry from the Gemfile, running `bundle install`, dropping to `irb`, and running `require "metasm/metasm"` returns the same cannot load such file.

Comment: @Chiggins and after entering the console using `bundle exec irb` and requiring the module, the gem works as expected?

Comment: @LucasCosta Huh it seems that way! I just figured that after the require returned false then it'd not be working!

Comment: @Chiggins Great! =) I posted an answer to help other people with this problem too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must enter irb using the `bundle exec irb` command.

As you can see [here](http://bundler.io/man/bundle-exec.1.html), the `bundle exec <command>` executes the command making all gems specified in the Gemfile available to require in Ruby programs.

Comment: Worked for me! Thanks Lucas!